# MacBook Pro (2011) with new Samsung EVO 840 SSD freezing (beach ball) on Yosemite

Tags: macos, ssd, macbook-pro

I’ve been using Yosemite for quite a while on HDD which came with MBP and it worked just fine. I also have MacBook 2010 with Intel SSD and also running Yosemite with no problem.

Now, yesterday I’ve got new Samsung EVO 840 SSD and I’ve copied my data from HDD using USB and then I swapped disks.  Booting was normal, quite faster comparing to HDD launch. I  got to login screen with my name and everything. So far everything looked normal, until I tried to login.

As soon as I move mouse cursor, beach ball appears and it takes about a minute to fill in a password. After hitting enter, I waited for about 10 minutes and still nothing happened, so I had to hard shut down.

Does anyone experience same/similar problem? Any suggestions what should I do?

Oh, I’ve also put Intel SSD (from MB 2010) into MBP 2011 and exactly the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Answer updated to reflect Apple's trimforce development: see [here](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/07/01/os-x-trim-ssd/)

Trim kext is altered in Yosemite. This is not relevant if you're using an Apple installed SSD. If you're using a DIY SSD, Trim support is tricky in Yosemite because of recent modifications to kext security management that affects Trim support. [More about Trim Enabler for Mac](http://www.cindori.org/trim-enabler-and-yosemite/).

> About Trim in Yosemite In OS X 10.10 (Yosemite),
>
> Apple has introduced a new security requirement called kext signing. (A kext is
>   a kernel extension, or a driver, in Mac OS X)
>
> Kext signing basically works by checking if all the drivers in the
>   system are unaltered by a third party, or approved by Apple. If they
>   have been modified, Yosemite will no longer load the driver. This is a
>   means of enforcing security, but also a way for Apple to control what
>   hardware that third party developers can release OS X support for.
>
> Since Trim Enabler works by unlocking the Trim driver for 3rd party
>   SSD’s, this security setting prevents Trim Enabler to enable Trim on
>   Yosemite.
>
> To continue to use Trim Enabler and continue to get Trim for your
>   third party SSD, you first need to disable the kext signing security
>   setting.
>
> It is important to note that the kext-signing setting is global, if
>   you disable it you should be careful to only install system drivers
>   from sources that you trust.

Some drives work without Trim enabled: [ZDNet on issues with Trim in Yosemite](http://www.zdnet.com/article/os-x-yosemite-and-third-party-ssds-heres-what-you-need-to-know/).

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, I've asked this question when I had Yosemite Beta installed, now I see that Trim Enabler is also available for Yosemite! I guess it's time to do some upgrade :)

Comment: Yes, BUT: If you wish to keep kext-signing security, read the links and the quote: in Yosemite trim is NOT SUPPORTED for most 3rd party drives even when using Trim Enabler. Sad but true, will have to buy another SSD myself or deal with headaches when resetting VRAM, and fusion or RAID0 looks to be out of the question using trim support. Just bought 2 Samsung 840 Evos for my folks to upgrade their older machines, now returning for OWC drives with Sandforce built in (making trim support unnecessary).

Comment: So, if you want to use kext-signing... The only way for proper use of SSD on MacBook Pro (2011) is to either buy SSD from Apple, or to buy 3d party SSD with no Trim support, but rather Sandforce? That hurts! :) Also, is there any serious risk if you disable kext-signing in practice? I mean, I usually don't use drivers which I'm not familiar with. Any thoughts?

Comment: Right? @oarfish did a nice summary of tradeoffs of disabling kext-signing [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/156331/104510). Personally I'm opting for headache free and secure Sandforce and making non startup fusion drives with my existing TRIM enabled SSDs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with installing a 1TB Samsung 850 SSD on my late 2011 MBP - it turned out it was the original HD cable was only SATA II compatible, and could not cope with the SATA III SSD data transfer speeds.

I bought a replacement from Amazon for £10, fitted it, now everything works fine.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B009SP84L0/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score -2):

Every time you move your data to another HDD or SSD after that you have to run Disk Utility to fix permissions.

This will resolve your problem. Good luck